# Javascript - draggable function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently doing my project that enable to drag and drop. I'm planning to create the clone become draggable (which can make it move around the div) after it dropped inside the 'div="dropzone"'. Below is the script.

Script:

```
<script>
var box = document.getElementById("div1");

var boxLeft = box.offsetLeft;
var boxTop = box.offsetTop;
box.ondrop = drop;
box.ondragover = allowDrop;

var img = document.getElementById("drag1");
img.onmousedown = mousedown;
img.ondragstart = dragstart;


var startOffsetX, startOffsetY;

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}


function mousedown(ev) {
    startOffsetX = ev.offsetX;
    startOffsetY = ev.offsetY;
}




function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) {

   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
   var dropX = ev.clientX - 650;
   var dropY = ev.clientY- 45;
   nodeCopy.setAttribute("style","position:absolute; top:" + dropY + "px; left:" + dropX + "px;");
   ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;


}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event) " > Drop here </div>
<img id="drag1" src="images/shoe.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onclick="click(event)" width="100" height="100">
<img id="drag2" src="images/LZK-Logo.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100">
```

Which I will drag the images (drag1 and drag2 ) to dropzone that make a clone inside the dropzone. And I need a way to make the clone inside the dropzone can move ( draggable ) around the dropzone without making clone again. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI has a great set of effects, widgets and themes built on top of the JQuery/Javascript Library they offer similar things maybe you should check it out.

https://jqueryui.com/

It is fairly simple to use also, check the following example after the required Jar files have been added it is as simple as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
     <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  <style>
      #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
```

Script:

```
  <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    } );
  </script>
```

Live Example:

[https://jqueryui.com/draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

They also have similar things for what you are asking, I would post the link but I do not have the required rep. Check out the events section of draggable widget.

It would be a simple case of manipulating the JQuery to the events you need.

Comment: jquery ui do help me for the dragging function but i unable to get the source to make a copy.